# Question about generated equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\sim$ the equivalence relation generated by $(x,0)\sim (y,0)$ for $(x,0),(y,0)\in X\times [0,1]$.

Is it true that $(x,t_x)\sim (y,t_y) \implies (x,0)\sim(y,0)$?

Comment: Something is wrong with the way you worded this question.  I mean, if $(x,0)\sim(y,0)$ for all $x,y\in X$ then the implication you desire is trivially true.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by "generated."  Do you just mean that the only equivalence class which is not a singleton be $X\times\{0\}$?

Comment: Let $R$ be the relation $\{ (x,0) | x \in X\}$, and $\sim$ the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$. I don't see my implication could follow.

Comment: The implication is trivially true, because the statement "$(x,0)\sim (y,0)$" is always true by your assumption. And "$P\to Q$" is always true when "$Q$" is true.

Comment: You have described $R$ as a relation between $X$ and $\{0\}$ (in particular the zero function), but you want $\sim$ to be a relation between $X\times[0,1]$ and itself.  So, something is very wrong.  As for the implication, you stipulate the condition  $(x,0)\sim(y,0)$ for (all?) $x,y\in X$.  You then ask whether some other condition implies what you just stipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the relation $R$ on $X \times [0,1]$ is defined by : $\{(x,0) \times (y,0) : x,y \in X\}$, and we are trying to find a property of $\sim$, which is the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$.

Actually, the statement you provide is obvious : because $(x,0) \sim (y,0)$ is true for any relation $\sim$ containing $R$ (remember, if a relation $A$ contains a relation $B$, then every pair that is $B$ related is also $A$ related).

The way to do this question would probably be to guess a good containment equivalence relation $R'$ of $R$.

Define a relation $R'$ as follows : $(x,t_x)\sim^{R'} (y,t_y)$ if and only if either $ x= y,t_x = t_y$ or $t_x = t_y = 0$. I claim that $\sim^{R'}$ is an equivalence relation. It is obvious it contains $R$, because if $x\sim^R y$ then by definition $t_x = t_y = 0$. Note that in either case , if $(x,t_x) \sim (y,t_y)$ then $t_x = t_y$.

Reflexivity is by definition (equality of pairs implies equality of components). Symmetry is clear because the description of $R'$ does not differentiate between the order in which $x,y$ appear.

For transitivity, suppose that $(x,t_x) \sim^{R'} (y,t_y) \sim^{R'} (z,t_z)$. Then, two cases occur : either $t_y = 0$ or $t_y \neq 0$.

If $t_y \neq 0$ then we get $x=y,t_x = t_y$ and $y=z , t_y = t_z$ from definition. Thus by transitivity of $=$ we get $x=z,t_x = t_z$ so transitivity holds in this case.

Suppose $t_y = 0$. Then , by the note I made, the given relations imply that $t_x = t_y = 0$ and $t_z = t_y = 0$, so that $t_z = t_x = 0$. Thus, transitivity holds now also.

It follows that $R'$ is an equivalence relation containing $R$. In fact, it is easy to see that $R' = \sim$, because $R' = R \cup \{(a,a) : a \in X \times [0,1]\}$, and any equivalence relation, being a reflexive relation containing $R$, also contains $R'$.

Now, the statement $(x,0) \sim (y,0)$ is true for *any* $x,y$ so in the implication you provide, the right hand side is always true! Thus the implication is trivial. The equivalence classes under $\sim$ are the singletons of $X \times (0,1]$, and the whole of $X \times \{0\}$ as one equivalence class.